# Parse cloud code: We are trying to call Spreedly API which in xml in cloud code

Tags: parse-platform, cloud

I am struggling to call an external API which is supported only for XML using HTTP Request (parse.cloud.httprequest). The cURL request format is :

curl https://core.spreedly.com/v1/gateways/UD0s1PcwgI55XJefzrlBBQMwaUj/purchase.xml  -u '60lRz6BfKxHESwJaVSf4kiZpu5O:xVqRwqem0KEuthvE9n8aIE1Al8FVL2QwdC2z8cS8jQYXAQER18wMW8SD6BhOF4fX' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d 'YsTXXDhYwePyMW8KlgeOmkZ1qlR100USD'

This (above) works fine. Now I need to call this XML API from Parse cloud function. The parse documentation on HTTP Request shows only examples of JSON not XML. Here is what I am using in HTTP Request cloud method but it is failing with 401 error.. Please help.

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method:'POST',
    url: url1,
    headers: {                  
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
        'Authorization' : "'"+environment_key+":"+access_secret_key+"'"
    },
    data: "<transaction><payment_method_token>cust_token</payment_method_token><amount>amount</amount><currency_code>currency_code</currency_code></transaction>"
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
     var response1=httpResponse.data;
     console.log("res :"+response1);
     response.success(response1);
}, function(httpResponse) {
     console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
     response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
});
```

Comment: Your curl doesn't show any Authorization header, -u isn't necessarily the same, and a 401 is an auth issue - so what exactly is the server expecting from you?

Comment: I want to convert curl -u key:value <options> <url> to Parse cloud code. I mean I want to run this command in cloud code. Cloud code is in Javascript. Cloud code itself is server code. It calls API and get back response (success or error). Right now its showing 401 error on API call.

Comment: IIRC -u in curl uses the negotiated security model specified by the server, so I'm not sure exactly what and how it will be sent to the server. Do you have a spec of what the server wants to receive for the auth details, and how ?

Comment: No any kind of spec, but when I run this command on terminal of my mac m/c it gives successful output and output is in xml format. They only provide above curl command in their documentation. I simply wants to run this command in my cloud code.

Comment: I'd use Charles proxy to check what is actually sent in the headers and body